# Perl WWW::Scripter, calling javascript from .js file

Tags: javascript, perl

The main html file contains following javascript source

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Hello Worlds</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_page.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page_content.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_page.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page_content.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/configurator.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

one of the form's post called a javascript function which belongs to `page_content.js` file.

I am trying to inovke the function using following

```perl
$scripter->get('javascript:submitForm()');
```

but it's not working. Please help me how can I call the function which belongs to the `page_content.js` file.

Comment: Please show some code. WWW::Scripter needs an engine to actually parse the javascript. Which one are you using? You probably have to parse the HTML and download the JS files. (but I'm not 100% certain)

Answer (score 1):

If the html page (with address stored in `$url`) contains (internally or externally) JavaScript that define function/procedure *submitForm()* then you can execute it by the following code:

```
use WWW::Scripter;

$w = new WWW::Scripter;
$w->use_plugin('JavaScript');

$w->get($url);
$w->eval('submitForm();');
```

For more information see [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.028/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod) documentation.